# Select box selecting next index for second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using bootstrap select picker for select box. It is selecting first time perfectly. But the problem is second time selection. For second time it is selecting next index value.

**Fildle:-**http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1214/

**Eg:-**
If I select `C` second time. It will select `D`

```
<select class="form-control nya-selectpicker selectpicker" name="subapp1"  
                data-live-search="true" ng-model="subappID" ng-
                ng-options="subapp.ID as subapp.DESCRIPCION for subapp in subapplicationList"  
                data-select-watcher data-last="{{$last}}"  >

        </select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button -- yes, you can use Angular in them) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: get rid of bootstrap.js and use existing angular modules instead